# How to correct determinate path varible in path

Tags: url

Suppose I have site  `www.mydomain.com` and it has this type of path:

`www.mydomain.com/order/123` where 123 is order id.

I want to add to this paths path few variables? For example it can be `?a=1&b=2` or `?a=1&b=2&c=cat`

How to correct build path:

- `www.mydomain.com/order/123?a=17&b=3`
- `www.mydomain.com/order/123/?a=17&b=3`
- `www.mydomain.com/order?id=123&a=17&b=3`

Comment: That kind of URLs are doing a Query. If you want to add that variable do it in the same way as you have done before with /order/123

Comment: @acostela Ok, but If I have few variables? For example it can be `?a=1&b=2` or `?a=1&b=2&c=cat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use.

```
www.mydomain.com/order/123/a/17/b/3
```

It translates like give me order 123 the object a whose ID is 17 and so on...

If you use

```
 www.mydomain.com/order/123?a=17?b=3
```

It translates like give me the order 123 whose var a is equal to 17 and var b equals to 3